# Get date using javascript in this format [MM/DD/YY]

Tags: javascript, date, getdate

how can I get the date in this format [mm/dd/yy] using javascript. I am struggling to get the 'year' to a 2 digit figure as opposed to the full 4 digits. 
Thanks!

Comment: Please show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Show us the code you already have

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

JS

```
(function () {
    // Get current date
    var date = new Date();

    // Format day/month/year to two digits
    var formattedDate = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var formattedMonth = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var formattedYear = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);

    // Combine and format date string
    var dateString = formattedMonth + '/' + formattedDate + '/' + formattedYear;

    // Reference output DIV
    var output = document.querySelector('#output');

    // Output dateString
    output.innerHTML = dateString;
})();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/4mLe1Lrd/

Comment: The dates and months could come out single digit.

Answer (score 15):

```
var date = new Date();
var datestring = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString()).substr(-2) + "/" + ("0" + date.getDate().toString()).substr(-2)  + "/" + (date.getFullYear().toString()).substr(2);
```

This guarantees 2 digit dates and months.

Comment: I think you need a + 1 on the getMonth()

Comment: @AdamRackis Yeah I edited a few seconds ago, just realised I put the increment on the date.

Comment: It's incorrect, getYear() will return year in three digits for year passed 2000, see https://tinker.io/a7188

Comment: @Nelson Updated, fixed the month and date too.

Answer (score 1):

How About this for the year

```
String(new Date().getFullYear()).substr(2)
```

And since you need your Month from `01` through `12` do this

```
var d = new Date("2013/8/3"); 
(d.getMonth() < 10 ? "0" : "") + (d.getMonth() + 1)
```

Do the same thing for days, Minutes and seconds

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/22sc6/)