# How to get 2 digit year w/ Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to find some javascript code that will write the current date in this format: mmddyy

Everything I have found uses 4 digit years and I need 2 digit.

Comment: not a big fan of substring are ya

Comment: May I suggest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184067/get-date-using-javascript-in-this-format-mm-dd-yy

Comment: how did you research this?  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: here's one for your great grandchildren to fix someday `new Date().getFullYear() - 2000`

Comment: "I need 2 digit"... really? You would die without 2-digit years? On the contrary, 2 digit years are probably going to cause you a lot more pain.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

### The specific answer to this question is found in this one line below:

```js
//pull the last two digits of the year
//logs to console
//creates a new date object (has the current date and time by default)
//gets the full year from the date object (currently 2017)
//converts the variable to a string
//gets the substring backwards by 2 characters (last two characters)    
console.log(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2));
```

Formatting Full Date Time Example, Single Function (MMddyy):

**JavaScript:**

```js
//A function for formatting a date to MMddyy
function formatDate(d)
{
    //get the month
    var month = d.getMonth();
    //get the day
    //convert day to string
    var day = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    //get the year
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    
    //pull the last two digits of the year
    year = year.toString().substr(-2);
    
    //increment month by 1 since it is 0 indexed
    //converts month to a string
    month = (month + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');

    //return the string "MMddyy"
    return month + day + year;
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(formatDate(d));
```

### Formatting Full Date Example, multiple functions (MMddyy):

```js
// function getMonth with 1 parameter expecting date
// This function returns a string of type MM (example: 05 = May)
function getMonth(d) {
    //get the month
    var month = d.getMonth();
    
    //increment month by 1 since it is 0 indexed
    //converts month to a string
    //if month is 1-9 pad right with a 0 for two digits
    month = (month + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    
    return month;
}

// function getDay with 1 parameter expecting date
// This function returns a string of type dd (example: 09 = The 9th day of the month)
function getDay(d) {
    //get the day
    //convert day to string
    //if day is between 1-9 pad right with a 0 for two digits
    var day = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');;
    
    return day;
}

// function getYear with 1 parameter expecting date
// This function returns the year in format yy (example: 21 = 2021)
function getYear(d) {
    //get the year
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    
    //pull the last two digits of the year
    year = year.toString().substr(-2);
    
    return year;
}

//A function for formatting a date to MMddyy
function formatDate(d)
{
    //return the string "MMddyy"
    return getMonth(d) + getDay(d) + getYear(d);
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(formatDate(d));
```

### Answers for full browser support (Internet Explorer)

### Formatting Full Date Time Example, Single Function (MMddyy): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/2zCkR/)

**JavaScript:**

```js
//A function for formatting a date to MMddyy
function formatDate(d)
{
    //get the month
    var month = d.getMonth();
    //get the day
    //convert day to string
    var day = d.getDate().toString();
    //get the year
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    
    //pull the last two digits of the year
    year = year.toString().substr(-2);
    
    //increment month by 1 since it is 0 indexed
    //converts month to a string
    month = (month + 1).toString();

    //if month is 1-9 pad right with a 0 for two digits
    if (month.length === 1)
    {
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    //if day is between 1-9 pad right with a 0 for two digits
    if (day.length === 1)
    {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    //return the string "MMddyy"
    return month + day + year;
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(formatDate(d));
```

### Formatting Full Date Example, multiple functions (MMddyy):

```js
// function getMonth with 1 parameter expecting date
// This function returns a string of type MM (example: 05 = May)
function getMonth(d) {
    //get the month
    var month = d.getMonth();
    
    //increment month by 1 since it is 0 indexed
    //converts month to a string
    month = (month + 1).toString();

    //if month is 1-9 pad right with a 0 for two digits
    if (month.length === 1)
    {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    
    return month;
}

// function getDay with 1 parameter expecting date
// This function returns a string of type dd (example: 09 = The 9th day of the month)
function getDay(d) {
    //get the day
    //convert day to string
    var day = d.getDate().toString();
    
      //if day is between 1-9 pad right with a 0 for two digits
    if (day.length === 1)
    {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    
    return day;
}

// function getYear with 1 parameter expecting date
// This function returns the year in format yy (example: 21 = 2021)
function getYear(d) {
    //get the year
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    
    //pull the last two digits of the year
    year = year.toString().substr(-2);
    
    return year;
}

//A function for formatting a date to MMddyy
function formatDate(d)
{
    //return the string "MMddyy"
    return getMonth(d) + getDay(d) + getYear(d);
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(formatDate(d));
```

Comment: Downvote because won't work after year 10.000 (jk xD) Btw, easily fixed with `.slice(-2)`.

Comment: If you are going for oneliners...


month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1).toString()).substr(-2)

Comment: @Merovex or just `console.log(("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1).toString()).substr(-2) + ("0" + new Date().getDate().toString()).substr(-2) + new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2))`

Comment: `var day = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2,"0");` no need for if statements...

Comment: @Salketer that's really cool, IE doesn't support padStart so it isn't a global solution like the function above.  Also i'm sure padStart is doing a loop and probably something like an if statement so from a code complexity standpoint you aren't gaining much i'd wager.

Comment: Interesting... About complexity, padStart is 10 times less complex than a for loop. It is way easier to use and read. I'm sure you meant performance wise, then I'd assume it would be pretty much the same yes

Comment: @Salketer correct i was describing Cyclomatic complexity, it probably is easier to read.

Comment: `slice(-2)` should be used even if you don't care about supporting >10000 dates as `.substr()` is deprecated

Answer (score 58):

Given a date object:

```
date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);
```

It returns the number as string. If you want it as integer just wrap it inside the *parseInt()* function:

```
var twoDigitsYear = parseInt(date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2), 10);
```

Example with the current year in one line:

```
var twoDigitsCurrentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2));
```

Comment: For what purpose are you specifying the second parameter of the `substr()` method? Wouldn't it be simplier to use `date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2);`?

Comment: @Alexander Abakumov You are right, when you are working with years which don't exceed four digits ;) This comes from my defensive coding style.

Answer (score 17):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getFullYear();
```

Yes, n will give you the 4 digit year, but you can always use substring or something similar to split up the year, thus giving you only two digits:

```
var final = n.toString().substring(2);
```

This will give you the last two digits of the year (2013 will become 13, etc...)

If there's a better way, hopefully someone posts it! This is the only way I can think of. Let us know if it works!

Answer (score 12):

```
var currentYear =  (new Date()).getFullYear();   
var twoLastDigits = currentYear%100;

var formatedTwoLastDigits = "";

if (twoLastDigits <10 ) {
    formatedTwoLastDigits = "0" + twoLastDigits;
} else {
    formatedTwoLastDigits = "" + twoLastDigits;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

another version:

```js
var yy = (new Date().getFullYear()+'').slice(-2);
```

Comment: why not use toString() instead of adding an empty string?

`var yy = ((new Date().getFullYear().toString()).slice(-2);`

Comment: personal habit, different behavior with null/undefined and also performance